# Encoder for update endpoint of a Rest API

Tags: scala, circe

I'm [implementing a client](https://github.com/ist-dsi/scala-keystone-client) for the [Keystone API of Openstack](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=update-user-detail#users). For the Users I have the following classes:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import io.circe.derivation.{deriveDecoder, deriveEncoder, renaming}
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}

object User {
  object Update {
    implicit val encoder: Encoder[Update] = deriveEncoder(renaming.snakeCase)
  }
  case class Update(
    name: Option[String] = None,
    password: Option[String] = None,
    defaultProjectId: Option[String] = None,
    enabled: Option[Boolean] = None,
  )

  implicit val decoder: Decoder[User] = deriveDecoder(renaming.snakeCase)
}
final case class User(
  id: String,
  name: String,
  domainId: String,
  defaultProjectId: Option[String] = None,
  passwordExpiresAt: Option[OffsetDateTime] = None,
  enabled: Boolean = true,
)
```

Where `User.Update` contains the possible fields to update a user. Updates are done using PATCH, or in other words they are partial. The encoders are being used in a class which has the methods to create, update, delete, get, and list the users. This service class uses the encoders in a http4s `EntityEncoder` with:

```
import io.circe.{Encoder, Printer}
import org.http4s.{EntityDecoder, circe}
val jsonPrinter: Printer = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true)
implicit def jsonEncoder[A: Encoder]: EntityEncoder[F, A] = circe.jsonEncoderWithPrinterOf(jsonPrinter)
```

My problem is how to implement the update for `defaultProjectId`. In the final json sent to the server the following cases are possible:

1. Keep the current value of `defaultProjectId` (the json object does not contain the field `default_project_id`:

   ```
   {
     (...)
   }
   ```
2. Change the `defaultProjectId` to `an-id`:

   ```
   {
     (...),
     "default_project_id: "an-id",
     (...)
   }
   ```
3. Unset the `defaultProjectId`:

   ```
   {
     (...),
     "default_project_id: null,
     (...)
   }
   ```

The current implementation: `defaultProjectId: Option[String] = None` + `dropNullValues` in the printer, models correctly the cases 1 and 2, but prevents case 3.

Ideally I would have an ADT like:

```
sealed trait Updatable[+T]
case object KeepExistingValue extends Updatable[Nothing]
case object Unset extends Updatable[Nothing]
case class ChangeTo[T](value: T) extends Updatable[T]
```

Usage example (probably in the future all fields would be `Updatable`s):

```
case class Update(
  name: Option[String] = None,
  password: Option[String] = None,
  defaultProjectId: Updatable[String] = KeepExistingValue,
  enabled: Option[Boolean] = None,
)
```

But I can't find a clean way to encode this ADT. Attempted solutions and their problems (they all require not using the printer with `dropNullValues` in the update method):

1. `Unset` is special:

   ```
   // The generic implementation of Updatable
   implicit def updatableEncoder[T](implicit valueEncoder: Encoder[T]): Encoder[Updatable[T]] = {
     case KeepExistingValue => Json.Null
     case Unset => Json.fromString(Unset.getClass.getName) // Or another arbitrary value
     case ChangeTo(value) => valueEncoder(value)
   }

   // In the service class
   def nullifyUnsets(obj: JsonObject): JsonObject = obj.mapValues {
     case json if json.asString.contains(Unset.getClass.getName) => Json.Null
     case json => json
   }
   def update(id: String, update: Update): F[Model] = {
     // updateEncoder is of type Encoder[Update]
     updateEncoder(update).dropNullValues.mapObject(nullifyUnsets)
     (...)
   }
   ```

   **Pros:**

   - Using the `dropNullValues` nicely handles the `KeepExistingValue` case.
   - If the user invokes `dropNullValues` to derive the encoder the code still works.

   **Cons:**

   - Because of `dropNullValues` the `Unset` case is meh.
   - We iterate twice on the Json Object field/values, once for `dropNullValues` another for `mapObject`.
   - `Json.fromString(Unset.getClass.getName)` is arbitrary and can collide with a legit value for `T`, although very unlikely.
2. `KeepExistingValue` is special:

   ```
   // The generic implementation of Updatable
   implicit def updatableEncoder[T](implicit valueEncoder: Encoder[T]): Encoder[Updatable[T]] = {
     case KeepExistingValue => Json.fromString(Unset.getClass.getName) // Or another arbitrary value
     case Unset => Json.Null
     case ChangeTo(value) => valueEncoder(value)
   }

   // In the service class
   def dropKeepExistingValues(obj: JsonObject): JsonObject = obj.filter{
     case (_, json) => !json.asString.contains(Unset.getClass.getName)
   }
   def update(id: String, update: Update): F[Model] = {
     // updateEncoder is of type Encoder[Update]
     updateEncoder(update).mapObject(dropKeepExistingValues)
     (...)
   }
   ```

   **Pros:**

   - Simpler implementation, `updatableEncoder` implementation maps more directly to the needed Json.
   - Just one pass over the Json Object field/values.

   **Cons:**

   - If the programmer invokes `dropNullValues` to derive the encoder then the code stops working.
   - `Json.fromString(Unset.getClass.getName)` is arbitrary and can collide with a legit value for T, although very unlikely.

I'm sure I'm not the first one to hit this problem, but I can't search for it, the best I got is [this comment](https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/584#issuecomment-346203481).

Comment: That's tricky. If I remember e.g. in Lucene-based search engines authors usually decide to make it impossible to remove a fields with partial update as it's hard to recognize client's intention. In your case if you have an optional string you could treat an empty string as removal request.